# Can AngularJS components modify their wrapper element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I like to think of Angular components as element directives. Given a component called `hero` I can use it in the parent template like this:

```
<hero myparam="something"></hero>
```

I'd like to use the `hero` element as a component-managed container, with the component being in charge of the whole element.

**EXPECTED**

Here's what I hope to get out of the binding from above:

```
<hero id="component123" class="alien" custom="foo">text</hero>
```

My custom component transforms the given element and uses it as it sees fit.

**ACTUAL**

However, it seems the component can only render its template **inside** the hero element. Best I can get is:

```
<hero myparam="something">
    <div id="component123" class="alien" custom="foo">
        text
    </div>
</hero>
```

I feel this is bad because the hero element is not actually the hero, but merly a wrapper for the actual hero. This mixes up the semantics and creates unwanted extra elements.

Is it best practice in Angular to use components as pure wrappers and putting the actual components inside?

Here's an official sample to play around with:
https://plnkr.co/edit/NKjCDS8OEngYHNrBmC5O?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I like to think of Angular components as element directives.

A component could be thought of as a special kind of directive that updates a template. If you want to change attributes, use an actual directive (attribute directive)

> My custom component transforms the given element and uses it as it
>   sees fit.

When you talk about transforming, you want directives, not components.

Comment: Hi @ScottL. Thanks for your insights. I've now read more about the topic and judging based on Angular and Angular 2 samples, the wrapper element is intended, even if the component has its own container.